Google Translate API Client has no "Translate_image" attribute
import os
from google.cloud import translate_v3beta1 as translate



def upload_and_translate(input_dir, output_dir, target_language):
    """Uploads all images in a directory, translates them using Google Translate, and downloads the translated images to a specified output directory.

    Args:
        input_dir: The directory containing the images to be translated.
        output_dir: The directory to which the translated images will be downloaded.
        target_language: The target language for the translation.
    """

    # Create a Google Translate client.
    client = translate.Client()

    # Get a list of all the files in the input directory.
    files = os.listdir(input_dir)

    # Iterate over the files and upload them to Google Translate.
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(input_dir, file), "rb") as f:
            # Upload the image to Google Translate.
            response = client.translate_image(
                f,
                target_language=target_language,
            )

            # Download the translated image.
            with open(os.path.join(output_dir, file), "wb") as f:
                f.write(response.translated_image)

# Example usage:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_dir = "example\path\to\things"
    output_dir = "example\path\to\finishedthings"
    target_language = "en"
    upload_and_translate(input_dir, output_dir, target_language)

Trying to use this script in order to translate a folders worth of jpg files which the google translate website will happily accept, not sure what to do from here.
AttributeError:
'Client' object has no attribute 'translate_image'

And
AttributeError: module 'google.cloud.translate_v3beta1' has no attribute 'Client'

are both shown when i attempt to run this, when this script has apparently worked for others in the past.
Not using a virtual environment, as I have read that it isn't necessary. Dependencies have been re-installed as well.
